# Cabecera de tabla se repite en ASP.NET CORE

Tags: bootstrap, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

Tengo el siguiente código que me muestra los datos de mi tabla en un table en `bootstrap`, pero al momento al parecer estoy realizando algo de manera erronea que causa que se repita la cabecera por cada registro.

```
<div class="row">
        @foreach (var item in Model.List)
        {
        <table class="table table-dark">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr >
                    <th >
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => item.CIE_CODIGO)
                    </th>
                    <th >
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => item.CIE_CONCEPTO)
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="col-sm-2">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.CIE_CODIGO)
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-sm-10">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.CIE_CONCEPTO)
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </table>
        }
    </div>
```

Me podrían indicar que realizo mal que causa este problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

5 cosas:

1. Rara vez respondo preguntas SIN intento de solución por parte de quien pregunta, haré una excepción porque veo que agregas respuestas a tus preguntas y las marcas como aceptadas, generando orden en el sitio, como debería de ser.
2. Lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822
3. Este workshop te será de gran ayuda: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY Es el panorama de ASP.net MVC, aunque es de la versión 5 con .net Framework "Full", los mismos conceptos aplican en ASP.net Core. Esas 4 horas son un resumen de una capacitación de como 27 horas de lo que en su tiempo fue Microsoft Virtual Academy (MVA).
4. Antes de copiar y pegar código, toma un momento de leer todo el código y hacer el análisis respectivo de lo que sucederá cuando ejecutes el proyecto. Acostúmbrate a esto y tendrás un gran poder: tener el compilador en el C:\erebro.
5. El motivo es que **dentro** del bucle, vas creando toda la tabla. Aquí te va código:

   ```
        <table class="table table-dark">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr >
                    <th >
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => item.CIE_CODIGO)
                    </th>
                    <th >
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => item.CIE_CONCEPTO)
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.List)
        {
                <tr>
                    <td class="col-sm-2">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.CIE_CODIGO)
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-sm-10">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.CIE_CONCEPTO)
                    </td>
                </tr>
        }
        </table>

    </div>
   ```

Comment: gracias por la guía

Comment: Un placer colaborar, éxitos con el desarrollo :D

Answer (score 0):

ASI QUEDARIA FINALMENTE EL CODIGO.

```
   <table class="table">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-center">
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => Model.Input.CIE_CODIGO)
                    </th>
                    <th class="text-center">
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => Model.Input.CIE_CONCEPTO)
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model.List)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td class="col-sm-2 text-center">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.CIE_CODIGO)
                        </td>
                        <td class="col-sm-10">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.CIE_CONCEPTO)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: Esta respuesta, ¿en qué se diferencia con la que otra? Es el mismo código. ¿Has leído el recorrido y leído cómo agregar respuestas?

Comment: Técnicamente es lo mismo, pero existen ciertas que difieren como el añadir que se centre el texto de la columna y lo hago por como dices arriba poner el resultado final de como queda mi código con tu colaboración.

Comment: Bueno... ok... No pasa nada. Saludos :D